# Separar varios registros en fila que están separados por coma en una misma columna python

Tags: python

En `Python` quiero hacer una separación de una columna que tiene varios registros separados con coma y que me coloque todo en fila y repita los demás valores de las otras columnas, tengo el archivo así:

```
zone    region  comune                                                                     TAC
center  5       San Felipe,La Calera,Hijuelas,Los Andes,Calle Larga,Llay Llay,San, 
                Esteban,Catemu,Panquehue,Santa María,Putaendo,Rinconada                                 
                                                                                           501
center  5       Puchuncaví,La Ligua,Papudo,Quintero,Zapallar,Nogales,Cabildo,Petorca       500
```

No puedo hacer que me coloque cada valor de "comune" como fila y repita los otros valores, algo así:

```
zone    region   comune       TAC 
center  5        San Felipe   501
center  5        La Calera    501
center  5        Hijuelas     501
```

Hice esto pero me da error cuando la columna "comune" tiene menos registros:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('D:\Documentos\SOC\python\EPLMN2.csv', sep=';')
  
new = data["comune(only reference)"].str.split(",",expand = True)  
  
data["comune1"] = new[0] 
data["comune2"] = new[1] 
data["comune3"] = new[2]
data["comune4"] = new[3] 
   
d_name1 = data[['zone','region','comune1','TAC']] 
d_name2 = data[['zone','region','comune2','TAC']] 
d_name3 = data[['zone','region','comune3','TAC']] 
d_name4 = data[['zone','region','comune4','TAC']] 
   
union_df=pd.concat([d_name1,d_name2,d_name3,d_name4],ignore_index=True) 

union_df.fillna('',inplace=True) 
  
union_df['comune(only reference)'] = union_df['comune1'].astype(str)+union_df['comune2'].astype(str)+union_df['comune3'].astype(str)+union_df['comune4'].astype(str)  
   
union_df.drop(['comune1','comune2','comune3','comune4'],axis=1,inplace=True) 
  
final_df=union_df[union_df['comune(only reference)']!=''] 
  
final_df.sort_values('region') 

print(final_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) en combinación con [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) después de hacer el `split`

Utilizando los mismos datos que pusiste en tu pregunta, desde un archivo "sample.csv":

Lo primero que hay que hacer es separar todos los elementos de cada fila de la columna "comune" y convertirlos a una serie

```
s = df['comune'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
```

Esto va a devolver una serie multi índice, es decir tiene dos índices, el original, que era `0` y `1` y un nuevo índice que indica la posición de cada palabra al haber hecho el `split`.

**Nota:** Con el fin de hacer más breve la respuesta no voy a agregar un ejemplo visual de lo que devuelve cada línea de código, te recomiendo ejecutar cada línea por separado para que entiendas el proceso completo de forma visual.

Para eliminar uno de los multi índices y quedarnos únicamente con el original hacemos lo siguiente:

```
s.index = s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
```

Y le asignamos un nombre a la serie, en este caso será "comune".

```
s.name = 'comune'
```

El conjunto de estas líneas de código nos devuelve la siguiente serie:

```
0     San Felipe
0      La Calera
0       Hijuelas
0      Los Andes
0    Calle Larga
0      Llay Llay
0            San
0        Esteban
0         Catemu
0      Panquehue
0    Santa María
0       Putaendo
0      Rinconada
1     Puchuncaví
1       La Ligua
1         Papudo
1       Quintero
1       Zapallar
1        Nogales
1        Cabildo
1        Petorca
Name: comune, dtype: object
```

Vamos a eliminar la columna original:

```
del df['comune']
```

Luego agregamos nuestra serie al `dataframe` original:

```
df = df.join(s)
```

Y por último utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) para reasignar índices únicos para cada fila

```
df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

# Obtenemos el dataframe original
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=';')

# Separa el string cada coma y crea una serie
s = df['comune'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
# Alineamos el índice con el del dataframe original
s.index = s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
# Damos el nombre a la serie
s.name = 'comune'

# Eliminamos la columna original
del df['comune']
# Hacemos join con la serie que creamos
df = df.join(s)
# Reseteamos el índice para que cada fila tenga un índice único
df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`

```
      zone  region  TAC       comune
0   center       5  501   San Felipe
1   center       5  501    La Calera
2   center       5  501     Hijuelas
3   center       5  501    Los Andes
4   center       5  501  Calle Larga
5   center       5  501    Llay Llay
6   center       5  501          San
7   center       5  501      Esteban
8   center       5  501       Catemu
9   center       5  501    Panquehue
10  center       5  501  Santa María
11  center       5  501     Putaendo
12  center       5  501    Rinconada
13  center       5  500   Puchuncaví
14  center       5  500     La Ligua
15  center       5  500       Papudo
16  center       5  500     Quintero
17  center       5  500     Zapallar
18  center       5  500      Nogales
19  center       5  500      Cabildo
20  center       5  500      Petorca
```